# Subfolders in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require, subdirectory

I have a module called user_searches.  It performs some searches that aren't core to the user model, thus, why I'm putting the responsibility somewhere else.  I want to organize all my models like this that perform non-core user functions in a lib subfolder called user.  Right now to include the module's methods in the User model I have to put...

```
require 'user/user_searches'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UserSearches

end
```

...I don't need the require if the file is directly in the lib folder, but do if it's in the subfolder.  What do I have to do so I don't need the *require*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the necessary require lines into `lib/user.rb` that way, all requirements are loaded recursively on application launch.

Alternatively, you could put something like this into an initializer:

```
# put into config/initializers/load_lib.rb
Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require(f) }
```

It will require all ruby files in your lib folder. You just have to make sure if this is really what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

This is works that cause

in file rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb in method default_load_paths initialized to load path just the lib folder without subdirectories, to solve this you can edit your project ` environment.rb config file and push into config.load_path array all subdirs.

Comment: For Rails 2.x, as per documentation in environment.rb, add the following: `config.autoload_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/extra )`