# Where to Rake Task specific classes live? (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, directory-structure

I have a couple classes that are used only by a rake task.  I realize that rake tasks normally live @ lib/tasks/whatever.rake but where should i place the supporting classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$RAILS_ROOT/lib` or `$RAILS_ROOT/lib/special_task/` would probably be the best as its in the default load path and you can do a simple `require 'my_task_helper'` or `require 'special_task/helper'` respectively.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what should i name the class?  You're suggesting i require it via 'special_task/helper' and it's throwing me off a bit.  thanks!

Comment: Yeah 'special_task/helper' and 'my_task_helper' were just an example. You could try just naming the files `lib/<task_name>_utils.rb` or `lib/<task_name>_helper.rb`. What I was getting at with the directory was if you had a bunch for different tasks utility classes and/or lib/ started to get messy, you could put them in a separate directories to organize it a little.

Comment: Ah thank you.  I was not sure of the proper naming convention for the classes.  Right now it's just "my_class_name.rb".  I should update it and the class name to be WhateverHelper.

Answer (score 1):

Directly inside "lib", if you're loading the Rails environment for the tasks.

You can also make them plugins if there are too many of them.

Comment: Plugins are deprecated in Rails 3.2 and removed in Rails 4, but if you have a larger number of files you can always [use subfolders in /lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981267/subfolders-in-lib).