# Trouble on extending Rails in a sub-directory of the 'lib' directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, extending

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and I would like to extend the framework with a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) located in a sub-directory of the `lib/` directory. I implemented the following:

```
# lib/extension/rails/custom_validator.rb
module Extension
  module Rails
    class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

After I restart the server I get the `Unknown validator: 'CustomValidator'` error. How can I solve the problem?

---

*Note I*: In the `config/application.rb` file I stated `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`.

*Note II*: If I put the `custom_validator.rb` file "directly under" the `lib/` directory (that is, without "sub-directoring" the file) and I use the following code then it works.

```
# lib/custom_validator.rb
class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Where/how are you using this validator (ie what does the backtrace for the exception look like) ?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981267/subfolders-in-lib

Comment: I opened a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906040).

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a file in the lib folder named "extension.rb" with the following content

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

module Extension
    module Rails
        autoload :CustomValidator, "extension/rails/custom_validator"
    end
end
```

checkout http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html and https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/c8f4627bf046680abb85665f28ab926e36c931db/lib/thin.rb for how this technique is used.

The previous code assumes that you've written your validator like following

```
# lib/extension/rails/custom_validator.rb
module Extension
  module Rails
    class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

And that you've included it in your model like the following

```
class MyModel
  validates_with Extension::Rails::CustomValidator
end
```

Another option would be to define the validator as follows

```
# lib/extension/rails/custom_validator.rb

class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # ...
end
```

and then add its directory to the load path of your application

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/extension/rails)
```

And in your model use the following to validate

```
class MyModel
  validates :my_property, :presence => true, :custom => true
end
```

Comment: you may need to add the following to the beginning of the file. see edit. $:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

Comment: What makes the `$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` code? What is it intended for? However, even adding that code, I am still getting the `Unknown validator: 'CustomValidator'` error. It seems that the `extension.rb` file is never loaded...

Comment: This code adds the current folder to the load path. which you already did in application.rb but I thought it may help

Comment: Can you please post the code for the model (how do you include the validator in the model?)

Comment: I do *not* `include` the `CustomValidator` class in the model. It is inheriting from `ActiveModel::EachValidator` and I am using it as in the second example present in the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) related to Custom Validators.

Comment: *BTW*: I opened a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906040).

Comment: I see, so you use something like :custom => true in the validation line. In this case you will need to have your class in the global namespace and add the path of the custom_validator.rb in the load paths. see my edits

Comment: At this time, in order to accomplish the same as the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/extension/rails)` statement, I am using the `require` method in a `config/inizializers.rb` file. What do you think about? What is the best choice between the two approaches?