# Is it a proper way to implement a custom validator in the 'lib/' directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9. A way to solve "[Trouble on extending Rails in a sub-directory of the 'lib' directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893659)" related to [Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) was to state the following code (note the directory where the file is located)

```
# lib/extension/rails/custom_validator.rb
class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # ...
end
```

*and* to put the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/extension/rails)` statement in the `config/application.rb` file. This way the `CustomValidator` is correctly loaded when starting the server and my `lib/` directory is organized as I'd expect.

However, I would like to know if that is a "proper" / "right" way to make these kind of things in RoR. In other words, is there a better approach to accomplish the same?

---

*Note*: In order to organize code in files I am thinking to namespace classes as-like the following:

```
# lib/extension/rails/custom_validator.rb
module Extension
  module Rails
    class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

But, by using the above code, it seems that there isn't an easy way to make the `CustomValidator` to work, even if I state `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in the `config/application.rb` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a file under the `lib/` directory that requires your rails extensions:

```
# lib/extension.rb
require 'extension/rails/custom_validator'
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases custom validators belong to the application domain. So the best place for it is `app/validators`. There is a great post about this here http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/

Comment: In my case the customs validator could belong to many application domains since it is for general purposes. So it should go in the `lib/` directory (at least for me), even more after reading the linked post and related comments.